# Where should I ask my printer-installation question?

Tags: support, scope

I just asked:

[Missing a driver for a SMB-accessed Brother printer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404824/missing-a-driver-for-a-smb-accessed-printer)

but on second thought - would it be better to ask it on superuser.com or on askubuntu.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is on-topic here, there's no doubt about it. It would also be on-topic on Ask Ubuntu and on Super User.

Your question requires knowledge about a specific piece of hardware, and it's always hard to find someone who has experience of that specific model. But maybe someone can advise on SMB printers in general, or on Brother printers.

If there's a way to use the Windows machine as a printer server, people on SU are more likely to know it, since SU has Windows expertise. I'd guess that your chances of getting an answer that doesn't involve knowledge of the Windows server are about the same on AU and on U&L, and lower on SU.